# SQL 2000: Stored Procedures Error : Procedure or Function 'name' expects parameter '@param', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is declared as follows:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.thisProc
 @ID int,@TypeID int, @DocID int, @Section varchar(10)
```

What I need is to be able to do this:

If @ID is supplied, execute a particular if block
if @ID is not supplied then move check if @TypeID is input and then execute another if block.

I don't want to write multiple sql queries to deal with different inputs/page sections that a user is viewing.

Thanks.

SAMPLE CODE:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE GetArticle
    @ID int,@DoTypeID int, @DocID int, @Sec varchar(10)
AS
IF @ID IS NOT NULL AND , @DocID IS NOT NULL  AND @Sec = 'inner'
BEGIN
  SELECT  "my query is here" 

WHERE Articles.ID = @ID AND Articles.DocID = @DocID  

END
ELSE IF @ID IS NULL AND @DocID  IS NULL  AND @Sec  = 'list'
BEGIN
    EXEC GetDocList @DocTypeID
END

ELSE IF @ID IS NULL AND @DocID  IS NULL  AND @Sec = 'full'
BEGIN
EXEC GetDocList @DocTypeID
END
```

Comment: Can you not just supply ID as -1 if you don't want to use it and use an IF stataement?

Comment: I don't think that'd be wise, SLC. Special values like that always end in confusion. @Kenyana, from the sound of you requirements, you *are* writing multiple SQL procedures, but stuffing them all into the same 'procedure'.

Comment: Yes Brian. I want to run multiple procedures based on inputs provided. Problem is that the inputs don't have to be there. I might have 3 or 2 variables provided. Can this work in SP or I have to code this in my .cs file then run the procedure with an say 2 inputs

Answer (score 1):

Just give @id a default value of null. E.g.

```
@id int = null
```

Comment: ...and don't pass any value in that parameter. That is, you don't have to pass a null value in the @id parameter, just don't include it.

Comment: I presume that is what he is doing anyway, hence the "missing parameter" error message ;-)